# Converting new statements in java to objective-c

Tags: java, objective-c, porting

How would I go about converting the following code in Java to objective-c?

```
return new Version[]{
        new Version(1, new int[]{},
                    new ECBlocks(7, new ECB(1, 19)),
                    new ECBlocks(10, new ECB(1, 16)),
                    new ECBlocks(13, new ECB(1, 13)),
                    new ECBlocks(17, new ECB(1, 9))), etc...
```

Just need a bit of a start point.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about porting `Version`, `ECBlocks`, and `ECB` to Obj-C first?

Comment: What about to write it into readable Java code first? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you've got to decide whether to use a C array or an Objective-C object (NSArray) for the array.

Then, in general, each `new XYZ(p1, p2, p3)` turns into:

`[[XYZ alloc] initWithParm1:p1 parm2:p2 parm3:p3]`